# dpkg gnome-settings configuration errors after installing gnome 40 on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, dpkg, update-alternatives

I ran the following command to install GNOME Vanilla on Ubuntu 21.10:

`sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop`

This worked successfully and I was able to log into GNOME 40.4. But I got a random dpkg error, as follows:

```
Setting up vanilla-gnome-default-settings (20.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gdm3-theme.gresource
dpkg: error processing package vanilla-gnome-default-settings (--configure):
 installed vanilla-gnome-default-settings package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vanilla-gnome-desktop:
 vanilla-gnome-desktop depends on vanilla-gnome-default-settings; however:
  Package vanilla-gnome-default-settings is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package vanilla-gnome-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 vanilla-gnome-default-settings
 vanilla-gnome-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It persisted while using the Ubuntu DE and the Gnome DE. Gnome settings itself seems to be working. After this, now I'm getting the following error after any apt command:

```
Setting up vanilla-gnome-default-settings (20.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gdm3-theme.gresource
dpkg: error processing package vanilla-gnome-default-settings (--configure):
 installed vanilla-gnome-default-settings package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vanilla-gnome-desktop:
 vanilla-gnome-desktop depends on vanilla-gnome-default-settings; however:
  Package vanilla-gnome-default-settings is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package vanilla-gnome-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 vanilla-gnome-default-settings
 vanilla-gnome-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but this happened:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up vanilla-gnome-default-settings (20.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gdm3-theme.gresource
dpkg: error processing package vanilla-gnome-default-settings (--configure):
 installed vanilla-gnome-default-settings package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vanilla-gnome-desktop:
 vanilla-gnome-desktop depends on vanilla-gnome-default-settings; however:
  Package vanilla-gnome-default-settings is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package vanilla-gnome-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vanilla-gnome-default-settings
 vanilla-gnome-desktop
```

I'm running all of this on an Ubuntu 21.10 install in Gnome Boxes (downloaded using the built in OS download option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [well-know bug. See #1935767](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-gnome-default-settings/+bug/1935767).

Take a look at [comment3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-gnome-default-settings/+bug/1935767/comments/3) by [Paul Broadhead](https://launchpad.net/%7Epjbroad) (code formatting my own):

> I have a manual fix for this.
>
> Edit "`/var/lib/dpkg/info/vanilla-gnome-default-settings.postinst`"
>
> Change "`gdm3-theme.gresource`" to "`gdm-theme.gresource`"
>
> Then "`sudo apt install -f`"
>
> The vanilla gnome setup now works as expected.

You can fix it as follows.

1. Open `/var/lib/dpkg/info/vanilla-gnome-default-settings.postinst` with a text editor.
2. Find `gdm3-theme.gresource` and replace it with `gdm-theme.gresource`
3. Run `sudo apt -f install` to fix.

Alternatively, here is a copy-paste friendly one line version of the above steps:

```
sudo sed -i "s/gdm3-theme.gresource/gdm-theme.gresource/" /var/lib/dpkg/info/vanilla-gnome-default-settings.postinst && sudo apt -f install
```